# Periodic Timers in C# and performance

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

In a lot of my projects, I find myself doing this:

```
var thread = new Thread(MyFunc);
thread.Start()

...

MyFunc()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ; Do something
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

An example use-case would be polling the DirectInput API for joystick input.
This is a poll-based API, not event-based.

I have recently been looking into how to achieve the same result using up-to-date mechanisms - advice I am getting is that Tasks are the modern way to handle async code.

So I did some digging on SO, and found some code which essentially does this:

```
_period = 10;
_cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
while (!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Task.Delay(_period, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    if (!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        _action();
}
```

However, it seems to use a LOT more CPU.
I have a test project [here](https://github.com/evilC/TimerPerfTests) which attempts to compare the two techniques and the associated CPU overhead, and it appears that the task based approach uses twice as much CPU
This is the first time I have used the VS perf test tools though, so I could be seriously mis-interpreting the results.
As I mention in the readme of the repo, CPU hit is important to me - this is for use in remapping applications which run while the system is under high load (Playing a game). I am willing to sacrifice *some* performance for nicer code, but not double the CPU hit.

There is also some code in the repo for a "Timeout" type timer (designed to be reset VERY quickly), any input on that too would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `_period`? Why do you switch to tasks?

Comment: _period will typically be the minimum system granularity, so ~15ms  
I have been told that I am "doing it wrong" if I am using a thread with an infinite loop and a sleep, and that there are more modern ways to do this - I am simply seeking the most elegant / robust / modern code

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer, because there is too much context missing for it to be considered a valid option. But have you looked at Reactive Extensions?

Comment: `Task.Delay` is definitely not intended to be used in milliseconds (or better) polling tasks, "up to date" or no (though neither is `Thread.Sleep`, for that matter). Per the comment of my namesake above, a fruitful technique is often to use a polling "basement" layer that's written in the most effective way possible with no regards for nice code, and then layer an event-based approach on top of that. The latter can use tasks, or Rx, or any pretty approach you like.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at Rx, but I find it pretty alien (I really have not got to grips with lambdas yet, something I need to address). Some of the stuff in there (Debounce, throttling etc) looks interesting though, so I can see myself biting that bullet at some point.